# Should Redis dynamic strings be unsigned int? why keep free instead of size?

Tags: c, redis

Since I need to use a key-value store for a project I am working on, I have been looking at key-value stores (Memcached, Redis) recently.  While perusing the features of Redis, and browsing the source code, I noticed that Redis has a dynamic string type (cool).

```
struct {
    int len;
    int free;
    char buf[];
};
```

I have used a similar approach previously, and was (pleased/amused) to see a similar data structure.  But there were a couple of odd behaviors.  I was surprised by the 'free' rather than 'size' semantic, and by the values being (int) rather than (unsigned int).

Should the elements len and free be declared unsigned int?

What would be better, a member 'free' storing the remaining space, or a member 'size' storing the total allocated size?

How often does Redis handle strings longer than (unsigned short int)? (64k)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I very much doubt that this is an error. My guess is, Salvatore chose this (int) delibarately because of "memory optimization/speed/avoiding casts", along with the fact that in reality this value can't get out of bounds. Possibly endianness was a factor as well.

The higher-level variable-length string types of Redis definitely don't have a 64k limitation. I've used strings of over 100MB (single key) in some cases.

Read the [docs](http://redis.io/topics/data-types): A String value can be at max 512 Megabytes in length.

Comment: Wow. 100MB in a single key. My use case was *lots* of small keys.

Comment: I might add that these are special cases, with dedicated redis servers. Always pay attention to the [`SLOWLOG`](http://redis.io/commands/slowlog) when concurrency performance is an issue. We keep slowlog entries around 10ms max.